# how to call a view that had it's id set with View.generateViewId()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, radio-group

i have a method called `addRadioButtons` that queries my database for the user's credits cards, and then display in as `radiobuttons` in a `radiogroup` in a `Dialog`. I save the `radiobutton`, and the `dataSnapshot` as a pair in a `HashMap`.

Now my problem is, when a user checks a radiobutton, i have no idea how to check if it's been checked because i dont know the `id`.

**addRadioButtons()**

```
if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
    val ll = RadioGroup(context)
    for (source: DataSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
        val last4 = source.child("last4").value.toString()
        val brand = source.child("brand").value.toString()

        val rdbtn = RadioButton(context)
        rdbtn.id = View.generateViewId()

        val textStr = "$brand ************$last4"
        rdbtn.text = textStr
        ll.addView(rdbtn)
        radioButtonMap.put(rdbtn, source)
   }
   radiogrp.addView(ll)
}
```

**openDialog()**

```
private fun openDialog() {
    val dialog = Dialog(this.context!!)

    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.stripe_layout)
    val lp : WindowManager.LayoutParams = WindowManager.LayoutParams().apply {
        copyFrom(dialog.window?.attributes)
        width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    }

    radiogrp = dialog.findViewById<View>(R.id.radio_group) as RadioGroup
    addRadioButtons()
    //HOW DO I USE THIS?!?
    //radiogrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener
```

Comment: Generate id out of for loop and assign to a variable and give ids like `generatedId + index` in the loop. Then you can get buttons with the same logic.

Comment: @underoid `generateViewId` produces an `Int` tho, so adding the index, wouldn't really make sense no?

Comment: I mean index of your for loop which is also an Int would make sense I think.

Comment: @underoid so for example `generateViewId` generates an int id of `10`, and index is `1`, so the id will be `11`?

Comment: @underoid oh ok i see, i think i get what you mean now, i'll ge tit a try

Comment: @underoid i can't seem to get the buttons after adding the radio button to the `radiogrp` view. I've tried `val card1 = dialog.findViewById<RadioButton>(viewId+index)` (the id's are the same, i did a `Log.d` to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you not use View tags for some sort of unique identifier?

E.g:

```
val rd = RadioGroup(context)
val records = listOf(
    "a" to "some record",
    "b" to "some record",
    "c" to "some record"
)
for (record in records) {
    val btn = RadioButton(context)
    btn.tag = record.first
    btn.id = View.generateViewId()
    rd.addView(btn)
}
radio_group.addView(rd)
rd.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, checkedId ->
    val btn = radio_group.findViewById<RadioButton>(checkedId)
    println(btn.tag)
}
```

So you can do `val btn = radio_group.findViewWithTag<RadioButton>("a")` if needed be.